# Compile + Run a Single File in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to somehow script Visual Studio to build and run **single files** (when no project is open)?
(Maybe with macros?)

Ideally, I'd supply the program and the command line to invoke, and it would automatically invoke them when I press F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no. For older versions of .NET, you can use [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/), but it hasn't been updated in a while

Comment: Well, if you are thinking macro-able stuff, you can create a dummy sln that exists only to compile your single file. But then you end up with a project open :|